# firebase cli tools firebase init not working

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I´m trying to run the firebase cli to create a host project but is returning the following ->

> Platform Information

On Windows

> Steps to reproduce

firebase init

> Expected behavior

create config file firebase.json at project root

> Actual behavior

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

```
D:\projetos\portfolio_project\jobs\templates

[info]
=== Project Setup
[info]
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info]
[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:51.589Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?page_size=100

[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:53.158Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:53.795Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectId' of undefined
at C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\init\features\project.js:48:23
at arrayMap (C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:639:23)
at Function.map (C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9556:14)
at C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\init\features\project.js:46:21
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[error]
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Try going to `https://console.firebase.google.com/` and setting up a project. After I built a project in the firebase console it linked up just fine when doing a `firebase init`.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I have 2 google accounts and I was trying to access through firebase cli the one that had no firebase project.

I created a new project with the user account I´m using in the firebase-cli and access was granted as expected.